# Debugging a C++ program that exits unexpectedly without error on lxc container

Tags: c++, debugging, lxc, ubuntu-15.04

I’m trying to build a c++ program in an LXC container.

It’s working fine in my ‘build’ container, and if i clone it - still works fine. If I create a new container and install the same build tools it builds fine and installs fine though the program seems to exit very early (before welcome message) with status 0

No logs, errors, etc. How should I go about debugging a runtime error like this?

Comment: Are there a differene in the container configuration? it may be ram default

Answer (score 0):

Please read something about `gdb`.